# immediate price change while typing number or changing radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, calculator, dreamweaver

I m writing a code using adobe dreamweaver. It is a price calculator that calculates the price immediately while changing radio buttons or typing number into input text. It works while the javascript code is inside of html file. But when I put the code into a sparate javascript file it doesen't work properly and when I change radio button the price doesen't change automatically and I have to type "facadeArea" and hit enter in order to see the changed "total price". please help me.

```
<html>
<font face="Algerian">
    <h2>
        What Kind of Project Would You Like to Order?
    </h2>
</font>
<form name="mdl">


    <div>
        Project style:
    </div>
    <div>
        &nbsp &nbsp
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">modern &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" 
name="options" value="1.8" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">classic &nbsp 
&nbsp
         <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.6" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">traditional &nbsp &nbsp
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.7" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">prarmetric &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" 
name="options" value="1.3" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">organic
        <input type="hidden" name="options">
    </div>
    <div> Project function</div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="style" value="1" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">villa &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" 
name="style" value="1.4" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">apartment &nbsp 
&nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.5" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">commercial
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.6" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">official &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" 
name="style" value="1.3" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">other
        <input type="hidden" name="style">
        <br /> Facade Area <br /> &nbsp &nbsp <input type="text" name="area" 
value="0" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">sqm
        <input type="hidden" name="area">
    </div>
    <br />


    <p>Total Price: <input type="text" name="total_price" value="0" 
readonly="readonly"></p>

  </form></html>



    <script>

     var ps = 'input[name="options"]:checked';
    var pf = 'input[name="style"]:checked'

    function estimateTotal(input) {
        if (!document.querySelector(ps) || document.querySelector(ps).length == 0) return;
        if (!document.querySelector(pf) || document.querySelector(pf) .length == 0) return;

        var projectStyle = document.querySelector(pf).value;
        var projectFunction = document.querySelector(ps).value;
        facadeArea = Number(document.getElementsByName('area')[0].value);

        var total = parseFloat(mdl.total_price.value);




        if (facadeArea == 0) {
            total = 0;
        } else if (facadeArea > 0 && facadeArea <= 1200) {
            total = parseInt(200000 + 166.7 *
                facadeArea) * projectStyle * projectFunction;
        } else if (facadeArea > 1200 && facadeArea <= 4000) {
            total = parseInt(400000 + 35.71 *
                facadeArea) * projectStyle * projectFunction;
        } else if (facadeArea > 4000 && facadeArea <= 10000) {
            total = parseInt(500000 + 16.66 *
                facadeArea) * projectStyle * projectFunction;
        } else {
            total = 700000;
        }





        mdl.total_price.value = total;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: did you include the external `<script>` file at the end of your HTML?

Comment: Yes, I did include the external <script> fie at the end of my HTML.